# making list of vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

Is there a quickest way to make a list as below in R?
There are numbers 1 through 18, and two elements are grouped.

```
list(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6),c(7,8),c(9,10),c(11,12),c(13,14),c(15,16),c(17,18))
```

Comment: Another option with `split` : `split(v1, rep(seq(length(v1)/2), each = 2))`.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `split` using a grouping variable created with `gl`

```
unname(split(v1, as.integer(gl(length(v1), 2, length(v1)))))
```

---

Or use `%/%` to create the grouping variable

```
unname(split(v1, (seq_along(v1)-1) %/% 2))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 1:18
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP has asked for the  *quickest way* to make the list. I suppose "quick" is meant in terms of typing code, not speed of execution.

The list of vectors can be created using a combination of `lapply()` and `seq()` :

```
lapply(seq(1, 18, by = 2), seq, length.out = 2)
```

A more concise variant of this approach would be

```
lapply(1:9, function(x) 2*x + -1:0)
```

This appears to me much more straight forward than splitting which requires to introduce a grouping variable.